# Fields with Additive identity powers

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Would it be possible to have a field (or field-like structure) with an additive identity $k$ where $k^a\neq k^b$ for $a\neq b$?

I need this because I'm working with a field-like structure where if I have a mathematical object $s$, $s+s^2$ doesn't make sense. Therefore, If I have $k^a = k^b$, I run into a problem by doing:

$$ s+k = s \;\therefore\; s+(s^2-s^2) = s \;\therefore\; (s+s^2)-s^2 = s $$

So I fix this by adding in the axiom $s^n-s^n =k^n$, which then leads me to $k^a\neq k^b$ for $a\neq b$.

Comment: No, the addititive identity is always "$0$".

Comment: When we're dealing with things like numbers yes, but I'm looking at a possibility where the elements in the field are more abstract objects. In that case would it be possible?

Comment: Oh, but I mean it satisfies the same rules.  For example try to prove that $k^2=k$ using the field axioms.

Comment: Even better, show $kx=k$ for any x in the field.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect my doubt a bit better.

Comment: Your new question doesn't make sense.  There is nothing to "fix" if you are in a field.  The new "axiom" is redundant in a field.  If you are not in a field then we can't help you because you didn't tell us where you are working.

Comment: Ok, I see where you're coming from. I'll try to give a better explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Try showing that $kx=k$ for any $x$ in the field using the field axioms.

Solution below if you are stuck.

> $kx=(k+k)x=kx+kx$ so subtracting $kx$ from both sides we get $k=kx$.